# Mongodb match two equal fields and loop over to perform function

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongodb query that outputs:

```
{"patientId" : "100", "action" : "DIAGNOSED", "date" : ISODate("2016-05-10T13:30:09Z")}
{"patientId" : "100", "action" : "DIAGNOSED", "date" : ISODate("2016-05-25T14:30:09Z")}
{"patientId" : "215", "action" : "DIAGNOSED", "date" : ISODate("2017-03-02T13:30:09Z")}
{"patientId" : "215", "action" : "DIAGNOSED", "date" : ISODate("2017-03-17T14:30:09Z")}
{"patientId" : "380", "action" : "PATIENT IN", "date" : ISODate("2017-02-03T13:30:09Z")}
{"patientId" : "380", "action" : "PATIENT IN", "date" : ISODate("2017-02-05T14:30:09Z")}
```

I need to be able to loop over this so that if the 'patientId' AND the 'action' are the same, I want to be able to do something (e.g. find the difference between the two dates).

I basically want to know the time it took for a patientId to go through an action and then find the average. So, for patientId 100 - I'd get a time difference for the 'action': 'Diagnosed'. Then I'd get the same for 'patientId' 215 for the 'action': 'Diagnosed'. Since these are both Diagnosed, I would find the average of the time differences. 'patientId' 380 would be part of a separate average because the action is 'Patient IN'.

My entire query has 8 different action types and 500 patientIds. I'm not sure if I can do this all in mongo or if I need to write some javascript to do loops because I need the average time for each action type.  I see how to do a match on a specific value in mongo, but not just "if they are the same...do this" sort of functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With MongoDB Aggregation Framework you can create a Pipeline of operations that resolve your initial question. Maybe you could also consider to create appropriate index for "patientId" and "action" if you got performance issue.

I also added some other property, just to give you the opportunity to understand more in depth how it work. For example **totalPatientInvolved** is a counter of records Grouped and **captureInvolved** is an array populated from all the Capture.

```
db.stackoverflow001.aggregate([
{
  $group: {
    _id: {
      patientId: "$patientId",
      action:"$action"
    },
    startAt: {$min: "$date"},
    endAt: {$max: "$date"}
  }
},
{
  $addFields: {
    dateDiff: {$subtract:["$endAt","$startAt"]}
  }
}, 
{
  $group: {
    _id: {
      action: "$_id.action"
    },
    averageTimeInMilliseconds: {$avg:"$dateDiff"},
    averageTimeInDays: {$avg: {$divide: [{$divide: [{$divide: [{$divide:["$dateDiff", 1000]}, 60]}, 60]}, 24]}},
    totalPatientInvolved: {$sum: 1},
    captureInvolved: {$push: "$$ROOT"}
  }
}
]);
```

Comment: Great, thanks! I think that should do the trick. I do think create appropriate indexes or javascript classes/objects might be a good approach, but at least I have a good start now. Never seen captureInvolved, good to know!